# pods update execute with errors in iOS terminal

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have next problem.

I try update pods in Podfile and get next errors in iOS terminal:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `FirebaseCore` required by `Podfile`
- `FirebaseCore (= 3.6.0)` required by `Podfile.lock`
- `FirebaseCore (~> 3.6)` required by `FirebaseAnalytics (3.9.0)`
- `FirebaseCore (~> 3.6)` required by `FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.10)`
- `FirebaseCore (= 4.0.0)` required by `Firebase/Core (4.0.0)`
```

This is content of my Podfile:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'PrayerDeck' do
pod 'Firebase', '~> 4.0.0'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Database'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'Digits'
pod 'TwitterCore'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'Firebase/Invites'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKMessengerShareKit'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
pod 'TwitterKit'
pod 'SwiftyStoreKit'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
pod 'FirebaseCore'
end

target 'PrayerDeckTests' do

end

target 'PrayerDeckUITests' do

end
```

I can't resolve dependencies of pods. Maybe someone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete Podfile.lock file from your project directory and try to install pod again.